# Where put and how call method common to several Xamarin Forms pages?

Tags: xamarin.forms

If I want to write a method that I can call from the code of any of my Xamarin Forms pages, and that will be able to do things on the UI -- a Popup specifically -- where do I put the method (App? AppShell?) and how do I call it?

VS 2019 Windows. Xamarin Forms app created from the New Solution Flyout template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a method in the `App.xaml.cs`,below is a sample for display a alertdialog:

in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public static async void Alert()
  {
     await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Warning", "this is a alert", "Cancel");

  }
```

call in other pages:

```
App.Alert();
```

Comment: Okay, and then App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert()